# Populate node field after feeds import

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-feeds

I have a situation where I am trying to clone a node field after importing content via feeds. I am doing this because of a challenge I have with `feeds_tamper_string_2Id` module. I have tried the following code but it didn't work

```
function members_entity_presave($entity, $type)
{
    if($entity->type == 'members') {
       foreach ($entity->field_tags2['und'] as $tags) {
          array_push($entity->field_tags_people['und'], $tags);
       }
    }
}
```

I want to copy the values of `field_tags2['und']` into `field_tag_people['und']`.

Answer (score 0):

If your field is a taxonomy reference you can try this :

```
function MYMODULENAME_entity_presave($entity, $type)
{
  if($entity->type == 'members') {
    $items = field_get_items($type, $entity, 'field_tags2');
    if(is_array($items)) {
      foreach ($items as $tags) {
        $entity->field_tags_people[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['tid'] = $tags['tid'];
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

You can use entity_metadata_wrapper : https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers

Comment: The field is an entity reference field that references taxonomy terms

Comment: it's the same process , juste remove 'tid' index, you can use entity_metadata_wrapper https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers